# Using ghostscript with TallyGenicom 6312 Line Printer

Tags: c#, .net, ghostscript, dot-matrix

I am attempting to use GhostScript 9.04 with .NET (gsdll32.dll) to convert and then output a pdf file to a TallyGenicom 6312 Line Printer. I've dug through tons of documentation but no matter what parameters I throw at GhostScript, and what type of output I try, I always wind up with a garbled mess of junk values as my output.

If I open the PDF in Windows and print direct to the printer, I get something that at least resembles my document, though it's somewhat unpolished. This is an automated process, so manual printing from windows is not an option.

The printer is on Epson FX-1180 emulation, so my expectation is that some form of ESC/P should work. Either I'm doing it wrong, or I'm wrong about that entirely.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a bit hard to know what advice to offer, since you haven't said what you've already tried. If it were me I would try the mswinpr2 device which works in a way which is pretty much independent of the printer. You can find information on this device here :

/ghostpdl/gs/doc/Devices.htm#Win

If you can print from Acrobat then that should work, but obviously I don't have your printer to test with.

Comment: I've found the mswinpr2 device to work well from the command line, eg: `gswin32c -sDEVICE=mswinpr2 -sOutputFile="\\spool\\\printserver\printername" -dNOPAUSE "C:\document.pdf"` however, calling this from code with the exact same params doesn't seem to produce any result at all.

Comment: How do you mean 'calling this from code' ? Are you forking a process or something else ?

Comment: I'm invoking the ghostscript dll, not the command line executable.

Comment: The command line executable (on Windows) uses the same DLL :-) So there must be some difference in the way you are invoking it compared to the way the command-line executable is working. Obviously I'm not really in a position to help much with that.

Comment: Either way, I just wound up invoking the command line and it solved my headaches, thanks for pointing me to the mswinpr2 device :).